# How to show simple (but customized) dialog in my own c++ application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, cross-platform, wxwidgets

I am looking for simple solution to get some data from the user by using dialogs.

I don't want to use MFC since it should be cross-platform.
I have read and run some examples of QT and wxWidgets but the problem is that they use their "own" main entry point so I don't know how to combine them in my application.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please choose the dialog! Press 1 or 2" << std::endl;
    int key = 0;
    std::cin >> key;

    if (key == 1)
    {
        Dialog1 dlg; //This is my question! how to do that?
        dlg.show();

        //Get data drom dialog:
        std::string str1 = dlg.GetData(ID_EDIT_BOX_1);
        std::string str2 = dlg.GetData(ID_EDIT_BOX_2);
    }

    if (key == 2)
    {
        Dialog2 dlg;
        dlg.show(); //Show simple dialog with some edit boxes

        //Get data drom dialog:
        std::string str1 = dlg.GetData(ID_EDIT_BOX_1);
        std::string str2 = dlg.GetData(ID_EDIT_BOX_2);
    }
}
```

I mean I *know* how to create and call dialog but don't know *how* to combine them in my app and call them in a *specific* line...

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-standarddialogs-example.html) link. It has fields that can be read back.

Comment: @yonatan, is you application console or GUI one?

Comment: @Igor, it is a console app

Comment: @Yonatan, why do you want to show a gui in a console application? Not that it can't be done - it just weird.

Comment: @Igor, actually it is opencv based application that should process some images. I want the user to modify the processing parameters and get the results with imshow...

Comment: @Yonatan, do you need `wxWidgets` or `Qt` solution? Also- if this is console application - why not just simply ask user to enter a number? Or if you want to work with the GUI library - why not convert to GUI application?

Answer (score 1):

With wxWidgets you can initialize the library using `wxInitialize()`, use `wxDialog::ShowModal()` to show your dialog and then shut it down using `wxUninitialize()` and repeat as necessary. It's obviously not very efficient to do it every time if you need to show many dialogs, but if you really want to make a totally self-contained function asking the user for the values, you can do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

For who are wondering I came up with a solution with small python script.
This script using tkinter popping up the dialog, and saving the results in text file.
i.e., I replaced the line:

```
dlg.show();
```

with:

```
system("python dialogScript.py");
```

And it worked fine.

The script works along with a parameters file that can be updated manually and the script should not be changed at all.
It parses the txt file on the fly and add controls according the parameters list.

Here is the python script:

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk

def OnClickOKButton():

    for i in range(len(parameters)):
    
        line = lines[i + 1].split(",")
        line[3] = str(parameters[i].get())
        line = ','.join(line)
        lines[i+1] = line
    
    file = open('parameters.txt', 'w')
    file.writelines(lines)
    file.close()

    root.destroy()

file = open('parameters.txt', 'r')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Configuration dialog")

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabControl.grid(column= 0, row = 0)

buttonOK = ttk.Button(root, text = "OK", command = OnClickOKButton)
buttonOK.grid(column= 0, row = 1)

lines = []
line = file.readline()
lines.append(line)
line = line.split(",")

tabs = []
for i in range(int(line[0])):
    tabs.append(ttk.Frame(tabControl))
for i in range(int(line[0])):
    tabControl.add(tabs[i], text = line[i+1])

while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    
    lines.append(line)
file.close()

parameters = []
lastTab = int(-1)
parameterIndex = 0
for i in range(len(lines) - 1):
    line = lines[i + 1].split(",")
    paramValue = tk.DoubleVar()
    paramValue.set(line[3])
    parameters.append(paramValue)
    if (lastTab != int(line[0])):
        lastTab = int(line[0])
        parameterIndex = 0
    ttk.Label(tabs[int(line[0])], text = line[2]).grid(padx = 15, pady = 15, column = 0, row = parameterIndex)
    if line[1] == "bool":
        ttk.Checkbutton(tabs[int(line[0])], variable = paramValue).grid(padx = 15, pady = 15, column = 1, row = parameterIndex)
    
    if line[1] == "double":
        ttk.Entry(tabs[int(line[0])], width = 15, textvariable = paramValue).grid(padx = 15, pady = 15, column = 1, row = parameterIndex)

    ttk.Label(tabs[int(line[0])], text = line[4]).grid(padx = 15, pady = 15, column = 2, row = parameterIndex)
    parameterIndex += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Then, the txt parameters file should be like this:

```
3,tab0,tab1,tab2,
0,bool,parameter1,0.0,description1,
0,double,parameter2,100.0,description2,
1,double,parameter3,100.0,description3,
1,bool,parameter4,1.0,description4,
2,double,parameter5,200.0,description5,
2,bool,parameter6,1.0,description6,
```